# Manifold homeomorphic to the smooth generator $\mathbb{RP}^4$ but not smoothly $Pin^+$ cobordant

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Related to [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2089019/), 
the $\Omega_4^{Pin^+}(pt)=\mathbb{Z}_{16}$. 
However, the topological $Pin^+$ bordism group is $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$. (This fact I don't quite understand well.)

There is a manifold $M'$ homeomorphic to the smooth generator $\mathbb{RP}^4$ but not smoothly $Pin^+$ cobordant to it.

The $M'$ has a $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ invariant equal to $(k \mod 16)$ as opposed to $\mathbb{RP}^4$’s $(k \mod 8)$.

> question: What is the manifold $M'$? That homeomorphic to the smooth generator $\mathbb{RP}^4$ but not smoothly $Pin^+$ cobordant to it?

Comment: What is the "topological Pin-bordism group"?

Comment: Check the statement here: "It is interesting to note that the topological Pin+ bordism group in 4d is Z8 rather thanZ16. There is a manifold homeomorphic to the smooth generator RP4 but not smoothly
Pin+ cobordant to it which has a Z16 invariant equal to 9 as opposed to RP4’s 1 (these numbers are equal mod 8)."

Comment: See page 10 of [this article download PDF on the right](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/JHEP12(2015)052)